Unable to Download .m3u8 File but Can Download .mpd Files with Headers – Can’t Find .m3u8 in Network Tab
Problem: I’m trying to download a video from a website that uses both .m3u8 and .mpd formats for streaming. The website is https://uzmovi.com/tarjima-kinolarri/6619-qaltis-kelishuv-qozgatuvchilar-premyera-ozbek-tilida-uzbek.html.
I can successfully download .mpd files by inspecting the page and using the correct headers (like User-Agent, Referer, etc.). However, I need the .m3u8 file to download the HLS stream, and I’m running into the following issues:
I can’t see the .m3u8 file in the Network tab (even after filtering for XHR or Media).
When I inspect the page, I see a reference to the .m3u8 file in the video element’s  tag:
html
Copy code

When I try to download the .m3u8 file using Python (requests), I get redirected to the main page.
I’ve tried using the following headers that I captured from the Network tab:
User-Agent: Simulating the browser’s request.
Referer: The page URL.
Cookie: Captured from my session.
Even with the headers in place, the .m3u8 request still redirects to the main page. However, I don’t have this issue with .mpd files — they download fine with the same headers.
Using Python's requests library with the captured headers.
Attempting to see if there’s a JavaScript-generated token that’s being added to the .m3u8 request.
Checking for cross-origin restrictions (CORS) by including Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Looking for additional query parameters that might be needed for the .m3u8 request, but nothing seems to be working.
Questions:
Why can I download .mpd files but not .m3u8 files from the same page, even when I’m using the same headers?
What could be the reason that the .m3u8 file doesn’t appear in the Network tab but is present in the page’s HTML source?
How can I correctly capture or construct the request to download the .m3u8 file?
Any guidance or ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
